# Unable to use ManyToMany Field with Django and Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I am working on a project with Django, Postgres. I typed that:

```
user_test = User.objects.first()
food_test = Food.objects.first()
user.food.add(food_test)
```

When I type that:

```
user.food
```

I got that:

```
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x7471bd30>
```

Then if I type that:

```
user.food.name
```

I got that:

```
AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Whereas the field name exists.

Models.py:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="default", null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class User(models.Model):
    food = models.ManyToManyField(Food)
    first = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="default", null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M2M relationship means - you have many objects.

`user.food.name` get attrbute `name` from M2M manager.

Probably you mean `user.food.all().name` - this code get attrbute `name` of Queryset.

Of course, I understand. You want `user.food.first().name` - this get `name` of first food if it exists or exception again, if `foodQueryset` contains Nothing.